# Does packed Chrome extension contains any connection to Chrome profile/user used?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I pack my Chrome extension, is there any data in the generated CRX which can be traced back to determine which of Chrome user profiles (and/or Google users the profile is synced to) was used to pack the profile?

I just binary-compared two CRXs packed with different profiles and they are identical *this time*, but are there situations when they can indeed differ, directly as a result of different Chrome profiles used?

Of course the same `.pem` is used at all times.

I use command-line call to packing, which looks something like:

```
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" \
  --profile-directory="Profile NN" \
  --pack-extension=Foo \
  --pack-extension-key=Foo.pem
```

Comment: You can create CRX using a [standalone script](http://priede.bf.lu.lv/ftp/pub/Tiimeklis/Google_Chrome/SRWare_Iron/extensions/_par_CRX_/crx.html) so there is nothing from the browser profile inside.